# XCode Problem - Couldn't load settings from contents.xcplayground

Tags: icloud, xcode, bug

I recently moved a few playground files from my documents folder to iCloud Drive. Then I noticed they all the files have been duplicated and non can be opened.
I moved them back to the original location to the documents folder and still they don't open.

Any suggestions on how I can bring back the codes I've written?

[image]

UPDATE:
I had a copy of one of the files in my dropbox. It turns out the playground file, consists of a few files and some files were missing or didn't get uploaded to iCloud. (iCloud bug? Shame!)

So then I took a look at the contents (right click > show package contents) and found a swift file which had my code in it.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you zip and unzip files and Mac turned some files into .xml file depend on your mac settings. The solution is:
right-click the "xxx.playground" file -> show package content, you will see the "contents.xcplayground" file. Right-cilck this file and go to "Get info". Now in file name and extension section, remove the .xml at last.

Do the same for "contents.xcworkspacedata" under the "playground.xcworkspace" workspace folder.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after moving my iOS development project folders from one place on my internal HDD to another.  I used a command line terminal window to navigate into my PlayGround folder and drilled town to:

*PlayGround/20160519.playground/playground.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/userName.xcuserdatad*

Finding *UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate* at the bottom of this path, I edited it and updated a number of file paths according to the folder reorganization I'd done.  I then navigated to *20160519.playground* and opened it with Xcode.  This time I didn't get the error; instead it gave me a *Loading...* message but the load never completed.

I think I'm on the right track to working around Xcode's location rigidity problem but there's apparently a detail or 2 more to find and update according to my folder reorganization.

Comment: I was able to pick up where I'd left off on my playground project by navigating all the way down to the *playground.xcworkspace* file and opened that with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some old playground files which gave the following error when trying to open them in a newer version of Xcode:

> Playground file is missing a "Contents.swift" file.

My solution was to right-click on the playground file and select **Show Package Contents**. In my package file, I found a file called *section-1.swift*.

[image]

I renamed this file to *Contents.swift*. After that I was able to successfully open the playground file.